# Samsung GS4 SCH-I545 broken after attempting twrp custom recovery

Tags: unbricking

I recently rooted my phone but was unable to find a custom recovery.  I just found this [post](http://www.progeeksblog.com/twrp-verizon-galaxy-s4-jfltevzw/) which I followed.  If you don't want to click on the link it basically says to put a .img recovery file on your phone and run android terminal to install with this code:

su

dd if=/sdcard/twrp.img of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p21

After doing this the phone shows this message: secure fail: kernel  along with a larger message start up fail and it tells me to use verizon software repair assistant.  That doesn't work.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install TWRP on a Verizon device so easily. In fact if your firmware is not early enough then you won't ever have TWRP since the bootloader is locked down by Verizon and devs virtually gave up on unlocking it. Read up [here](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxys4verizon.html) and the threads [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-verizon/Bootloader).

What you can do now is to use Odin to return your phone back to stock and at least working. Get firmware for your model [here](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/). Make sure not to downgrade, i.e. you need to know what Android version you were on before bricking and flash a firmware of the same version or newer. Simple instructions are on the download page itself, and detailed ones are all over the internet.